# How to convert string to snakecase format in python

Tags: python, string, python-re, snakecasing

I made a function that can convert every string to `snakecase` but some of my string creating a problem. I used `re` module

**ENTIRE CODE**

```py
import re

def toSnakeCase(string, restToLower : bool = False):
  string = re.sub(r'(?:(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z]))|[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', self.string).replace(' ', '_')

  if (restToLower == True):
    return ''.join(self.string.lower())
  else:
    return ''.join(self.string)
```

**INPUT**

```py
strings = ['hello world', 'HelloWorld', '-HELLO-WORLD-', 'Hello-World', 'hello_world', '--hello.world', 'Hello-WORLD', 'helloWORLD']

# using enumerate just to see which list item creating problem
for i, j in enumerate(strings, 1):
  print(f'{i}. {toSnakeCaseV1(j)}')
```

**OUTPUT** - Without `restToLower = True`

```
1. hello_world
2. Hello_World
3. _HELLO_WORLD_
4. Hello_World
5. hello_world
6. __hello_world
7. Hello_WORLD
8. hello_WORLD
```

with `restToLower = True`

```
1. hello_world
2. hello_world
3. _hello_world_
4. hello_world
5. hello_world
6. __hello_world
7. hello_world
8. hello_world
```

As you can see item **3** and **6** creating the problem. Someone know why it is doing this according to me my regex is right.

**Expected Output**

```
1. hello_world
2. hello_world
3. hello_world
4. hello_world
5. hello_world
6. hello_world
7. hello_world
8. hello_world
```

Comment: Please can you update your post with the expected outcome?

Comment: @Corralien I have updated my code.

Comment: Does this have to use `re` ? For the set of potential strings given this can probably be achieved more easily/clearly with string methods.

Comment: no there is no compulsory to use `re` module I used it to make my strings to pure strings i.e removing every other character except alphabets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems just to be the leading and trailing `_`, remove them before of after the the `space > _` conversion

```
def toSnakeCase(string):
    string = re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', string).strip().replace(' ', '_')
    return ''.join(string.lower())
```

For post-striping

```
string = re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', string).replace(' ', '_').strip("_")
```

Comment: Thanks man!!  I completely forgot about strip method!!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
def toSnakeCase(string):
    return re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|[^a-zA-Z]', '_', string).strip('_').lower()

for i, j in enumerate(strings, 1):
    print(f'{i}. {toSnakeCase(j)}')
```

Output:

```
1. hello_world
2. hello_world
3. hello_world
4. hello_world
5. hello_world
6. hello_world
7. hello_world
8. hello_world
```

Comment: It also worked!! Thank You . Btw @azro already answered and he used the same method. 